# How can I access a project's babel-related deps from somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-register

This is kind of a strange need, but I don't think it's an X/Y problem. I need to access a project's babel-related dependencies and config from my own tool. My tool might be a devDep, or installed globally, or run with `npx`; I have no way of knowing.

I know this can be done with `babel-register` because great tools like `babel-tape-runner` do it just fine. In my case, though, I can't just `require('babel-register')` and then require other files; I'm using `module._compile` under the hood. (Writing out a temp file, running it, and then unlinking isn't really a good option in this case, because it could potentially happen hundreds or thousands of times.)

Is there any way to babelify some code I've read in from somewhere using the user's projects local Babel config and presets and plugins, before passing that stuff to `module._compile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the right answer here was to just not use `babel-register`. I took a quick look at how Jest does this, and they use `babel-core` directly. Passing `babel.transform(code, { extends: babelRc }).code` into `module._compile` worked just fine. The entire diff is available [here](https://github.com/zacanger/jsdoctap/commit/1607b07455e43e49c930f4af3183c7211c39d37e#diff-6d186b954a58d5bb740f73d84fe39073R1).